# How to ensure that clearing UIElementCollection immediately clears my control's children?

Tags: silverlight

I have a Silverlight control which maintains a set of children. This set of children is quite rapidly updated during animations and a method that looks like this is called every time an animated dependency property on the control changes:

```
void SomeMethod(IEnumerable<ChildControlType> childControls)
{
    this.Children.Clear();
    foreach(var child in childControls)
    {
        this.Children.Add(child);
    }
}
```

What I'm seeing is a variable number of children on each frame, though it always converges to the required controls. That is, if, for every frame, I want 3 controls and send in an IEnumerable with 3 child controls, on most frames there are 3 children in the children collection at the end of this method. However, there are instances where at the end of of this method there are 12 controls, in the Children collection. This results in 12 controls being displayed in the control on some frames which looks ugly.

Can anyone explain why this would be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why I didn't think of this before, but calling the SomeMethod method using the Dispatcher solves the issue.

This has slightly confused me because I thought that the changed callbacks for Dependency properties were always called on the Dispatcher's thread. I'm also not sure why the "lock" statement didn't have the same effect in this case. I might have some reading to do.

Answer (score 0):

How is `SomeMethod` being called in this example?  It is possible that what you are seeing is due to multiple threads running the method concurrently.

I am by no means sure that this is the case, but you could test it by adding locking around your method:

```
private volatile object _lockObject = new object();

void SomeMethod(IEnumerable<ChildControlType> childControls)
{
    lock (_lockObject)
    {
         this.Children.Clear();
         foreach(var child in childControls)
         {
             this.Children.Add(child);
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. I've tried this just on the off chance. It doesn't work. Actually the call to the method is always from the changed callback of a DependencyProperty. As I understand it this callback is always called on the UI thread is it not?

Comment: I suspected so, but it was worth a try. In that case I'd assume that the adding of children is not synchronous. Maybe you could hide/show rather than add/remove?

Answer (score 0):

Its difficult to be certain but it sounds like a re-entrancy problem to me (these days we worry much about "thread-safety" we often overlook the ancient problem of re-entrancy).  Try this is tweak:-

```
bool inSomeMethod = false
void SomeMethod(IEnumerable<ChildControlType> childControls) 
{ 
    if (!inSomeMethod)
    {
        inSomeMethod = true;
        this.Children.Clear(); 
        foreach(var child in childControls) 
        { 
            this.Children.Add(child); 
        }
        inSomeMethod = false;
    } 
}
```